# Angularjs getting a 404 on image urls set in controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, controller, http-status-code-404

ok i have been working on this issue for a week now and i cant figure it out.

im working on a site built on angularjs and we load info from json files stored on the sever all this works but when the page loads for some reason one of the image tags always send off a 404 error but then it all loads fine

Example of error
GET http://localhost:3000/angular/::%20listp.titlePicture.urls[0].url[3].href%20%7C%20srcFill%20:%20%7Bwidth:447,height:351%7D%20:: 404 (Not Found) index.html:1

i have manually checked all 27 entries in the json file and titlePicture.urls[0].url[3].href is set for all of them

anyone have any ideas? the page can been seen here http://www.relaunch.bsf-immobilien.de/#/wohnen

this is the relevant ng-repeat code

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-ms-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="listp in filteredtodos | unique:'id'">
  <div class="panel panel-default relative" style="width: 100%; height:380px; padding-bottom: 15px; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;">
    <div class="ribbon-heading ribbon-default inline absolute left margin-none">
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferApartmentBuy'">Wohnung zum Kaufen</span>
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferHouseBuy'">Haus zum Kaufen</span>
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferApartmentRent'">Wohnung zum Mieten</span>
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferHouseRent'">Haus zum Mieten</span>
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferShortTermAccommodation'">Wohnen auf Zeit</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cover hover overlay margin-none" style="max-height: 250px;">
      <a href="#/wohnen/::listp.id::">
        <img src=":: listp.titlePicture.urls[0].url[3].href | srcFill : {width:447,height:351} ::" alt="::listp.title::" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      </a>
      <a href="#/wohnen/::listp.id::" class="overlay overlay-full overlay-bg-black overlay-hover" style="height: 143px;">
        <span class="v-center">
          <span class="btn btn-circle btn-white btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h4 class="margin-v-0-5">::listp.title::</h4>
      <p><span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferApartmentBuy'">Kaufpreis: </span>
        <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferApartmentRent'">Miete: </span>
        <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferHouseBuy'">Kaufpreis: </span>
        <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferHouseRent'">Miete: </span> ::listp.price.value | currency:'EUR' ::
        <a href="#/wohnen/::listp.id::">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg absolute bottom btn-circle right" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the URL, is it correct? or the variables need to be parsed

Comment: Post the relevent code. As of now the question is not answerable

Comment: added the ng-repeat code

Comment: Hey buddy, did you make sure:
1) The file exists in the server/local machine?
2) It's a valid url, try opening the url in browser?

Comment: the 404 error url is not a proper url it contain the template var that is sapose to be processed in the ng-repeat and yes all the image urls trying to be called on this page work is like the template try's to find the image before the controller data is set

Comment: I Have posted the answer below, i hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use ng-src instead of src, moreover one-way binding `::` doesn't need to be called twice in expression :

```
<img ng-src="::listp.titlePicture.urls[0].url[3].href" ... />
```

Comment: this was my issue ng-src stopped it from loading the var before it was set and our code is set to use $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('::'); and $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('::'); thats why the double :: instead  of {{

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't understood that at first sight. So be careful with the `::` notation as it may behave in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with your URL:

```
<img src=":: listp.titlePicture.urls[0].url[3].href | srcFill : {width:447,height:351} ::" alt="::listp.title::" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></a>
```

It seems you really want to access the value of an array `listp.titlePicture.urls[0].url[3].href` right?

In that case better mark it as an angular Expression, as follows:

I have corrected it in the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-ms-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="listp in filteredtodos | unique:'id'">
  <div class="panel panel-default relative" style="width: 100%; height:380px; padding-bottom: 15px; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;">
    <div class="ribbon-heading ribbon-default inline absolute left margin-none">
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferApartmentBuy'">Wohnung zum Kaufen</span>
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferHouseBuy'">Haus zum Kaufen</span>
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferApartmentRent'">Wohnung zum Mieten</span>
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferHouseRent'">Haus zum Mieten</span>
      <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferShortTermAccommodation'">Wohnen auf Zeit</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cover hover overlay margin-none" style="max-height: 250px;">
      <a href="#/wohnen/::listp.id::">
        <img src=":: {{listp.titlePicture.urls[0].url[3].href}} | srcFill : {width:447,height:351} ::" alt="::listp.title::" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      </a>
      <a href="#/wohnen/::listp.id::" class="overlay overlay-full overlay-bg-black overlay-hover" style="height: 143px;">
        <span class="v-center">
          <span class="btn btn-circle btn-white btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h4 class="margin-v-0-5">::listp.title::</h4>
      <p><span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferApartmentBuy'">Kaufpreis: </span>
        <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferApartmentRent'">Miete: </span>
        <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferHouseBuy'">Kaufpreis: </span>
        <span ng-show="listp.xsitype == 'OfferHouseRent'">Miete: </span> ::listp.price.value | currency:'EUR' ::
        <a href="#/wohnen/::listp.id::">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg absolute bottom btn-circle right" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this works fine for you..